# Javascript And CSS files loading problem

Tags: javascript

We have more java script and css files in our WUI project.

In some times, the files are not loading properly, due to the huge size.

Did any body face this problem? or Do you have any idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are they loading partially? What do you expect to happen and what is actually happenning?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem really due to the size of the files or is it the loading order?

Comment: Just how large are we talking, here? 200k? Or something larger?

Comment: more than 200k. like that i have to include 8 files.

Comment: try merging all of them into one file and calling that. (create a new file for the test).